# Virtuemart Image title in the middle of image

Tags: php, html, css, joomla, virtuemart

I am trying to move "Image Title" in the middle of the image but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<div class="product-field product-field-type-R">

        <span class="product-field-display">
            <a title=" Image Title" href="index.php/eshop/category/someproduct-detail">
                <img alt="getimagedpmk4xtm" src="/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/getimage_90x90.jpg"></img>

            </a>
        </span>

    </div>
```

I tried various stuff but none worked until now, my latest attempt is like this:

```
.product-field-display a title{vertical-align: middle !important;}
```

I know this is WRONG but i can't remind my self what other things I tried.

Comment: You could use `line-height` and set it as the same height as your image.

Answer (score 0):

You can style the anchor title with CSS3 like this, this is just an example on hover, you can now style it easily:

```
a[title]:hover:after{
    content: attr(title);
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    top:20px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    z-index: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the Image to be the background-image of you div and place the text inside the div.

for example:

```
<div  style="background-image:/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/getimage_90x90.jpg;">
   <span style="margin:10px;">
       <a title=" Image Title" href="index.php/eshop/category/someproduct-detail"/>
   </span>
</div>
```

this is just one simple way of displaying the text in the middle of the image. Also try first my sample code. I am not able to check the syntax of that.

I hope that I help you.